# Asyncio API. How get many str to second request.?

Tags: python

I have an issue in my code. Can you please help me to solwe problem .

The first request get me back ID

```
import requests
import aiohttp
import asyncio


headers = {"x-api-key": '*****************************'}
r = requests.get("https://**************************", headers=headers)
res_stat = r.json()
totalResults = (res_stat['results'])


for items in totalResults:
    results_id = (items['id'])
```

I getting back separate str (more then 1000)
In second request i try to get id inside in asyncio to make asynhronic request.

```
async def get_ids(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
        r.list = await resp.json()
        full_list = r.list
        return full_list


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
```

This part is wrong --- and i dont understand how to solw it.

```
names = results_id
for name in names:
```

This part is wrong --- and i dont understand how to solw it.

```
            url = f'***************************{name}'
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_ids(session, url)))
        candidate_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for all_data in candidate_data:
            return all_data

asyncio.run(main())
```